# Application Failure in Cydia Repo

Tags: iphone, cydia

I've recently made a repo for cydia and posted my application on it. When I download my app it installs perfectly find, but when I launch it, it will suddenly close. It works fine on the simulator, but I don't know whats going wrong. Can anyone pinpoint me to where I have a mistake. BTW I deleted all the DS_Store stuff out of the repo folder.

Thanks

Comment: I think you went wrong by publishing your app through cydia :) Collect the crash reports, then come back when you have something for us to work off of.

Comment: Had you tried a debug on the device? Simulator isn't the same as the device at all. Its good for quick fixes but large implementations really need to go via the device debug.

Comment: Yea, I did the build in Device 3.0 Release, and put that on my cydia thing

Comment: Have you tried to use the application straight from your computer onto your device before uploading to the cydia repo? Just trying to narrow down where things could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You probably either didn't sign your app's binary with ldid -S yourbinary, or didn't package the .deb file correctly. Follow this tutorial to make a repo/.deb file: http://www.saurik.com/id/7